# Moving from localStorage to chrome.storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I would like to use chrome.storage API to save the settings of my users instead of localStorage in my Chrome extension.

Currently my options.js (with localStorage and JSON) file looks like this:

```
$(function(){ //jQuery Ready

// INIT
$("#notifysav").hide();

// STORAGE
if(localStorage['options']){
    var o = JSON.parse(localStorage['options']);
    $("#option1").attr('checked', o.option1);
            $("#option2").attr('checked', o.option2);
    .... [list of options]
}

// Save Button Click event
 $("#save").live('click', function(){
    localStorage['options'] = JSON.stringify({
        "option1":$("#option1").attr('checked'),
        "option2":$("#option2").attr('checked'),
        .... [list of options]
    });
            // notification
    $("#notifysav").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
            // reload to apply changes
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: 'reload'});
});

});// #jQuery ready
```

My question is how to convert my current code to use the chrome.storage API. From what I understand, I would apply those changes:

```
$(function(){

// INIT
var storage = chrome.storage.sync;
$("#notifysav").hide();

// Load Options
loadOptions();

// Save Button Click Event
$("#save").live('click',function(){ saveOptions(); });

function loadOptions() {
     storage.get(         /* Something */           )
}


 function saveOptions() {

 var option1 = $("#option1").attr('checked');
 var option2 = $("#option2").attr('checked');

  storage.set({"option1":option1,"option2":option2}, function() {
   // Notification
   $("#notifysav").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
   // Reload Event to apply changes
   chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: 'reload'});
   });
     }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, your main problem is how to retrieve data from the storage. Here is what can be done:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(all){console.log(all)});
```

will return you an object with all keys and values stored in the storage, in your case it will output:

```
Object {option1: "value1", option2: "value2"}
```

Also you can get just one of the keys:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("optionkey", function(all){console.log(all)});
```

or an array of keys:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(["opt1", "opt2"], function(all){console.log(all)});
```

In any case you can access data in the callback just by key names.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I finally managed to get something working by changing my original code as follows:

```
$(function(){

 // INIT
 const storage = chrome.storage.sync;
 var options = new Array(); 

 $("#notifysav").hide();

 loadOptions();

 // STORAGE

  // Save Button Click event
  $("#save").live('click', function(){ saveOptions(); });

function loadOptions() {
  storage.get('options', function(o) { 

     $("#option1").attr('checked', o.options[0]);
     $("#option2").attr('checked', o.options[1]);
     ...
    });
 }

function saveOptions() {
     options[0] = $("#option1").prop('checked');
     options[1] = $("#option2").prop('checked');
     ...

//console.log(options);

     storage.set({'options':options},function(){
       $("#notifysav").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
       chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: 'reload'});
      });
    }

  });
```